# pip3 install errors out while installing screen on a docker container

Tags: centos, python, docker

I have a docker container running mysql, which was run as:

`docker run -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes -d mysql/mysql-server:5.6`

I copied over the python project (containing requirements), entered the docker container, installed `python36`, `python36-pip`, created and entered a `virtualenv` and executed the following command:

`pip3.6 install -r requirements.txt`

which led me to this:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 162: ordinal not in range(128)
```

while installing the package: `screen==1.0.1`

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I came across this answer here:

[Answer](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/2910)

and proceeded to change the locale language like so:

```
locale
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

This solved the issue.

Comment: The proper thing to do is to create a derived image using a Dockerfile that runs the pip installation.

Comment: It's possible that you might not have this locale installed in which case, run: locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

Comment: @xenoid , could you point to a resource which would help with the suggestion that you mentioned? Please ignore my "newbieness".

Comment: Try [this](https://linuxtechlab.com/learn-create-dockerfile-example/) but any docker tutorial will do. Creating a derived image using a Dockerfile is a fundamental step in Docker usage.

Answer (score -1):

Using pip from python2 instead pip from python3 helped